# Promesa devuelve pendiente en vez de devolver el resultado, (un token en este caso)

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, express, login, jwt

necesito consultar unos datos mediante una api en express desde una aplicacion en react, pero la promesa que me deve devolver los datos (en este caso un token) siempre me devuelve pendiente, he verificado los resultados con Postman y la api esta bien. Agradecería mucho si alguien me ayudara a obtener los datos que devuelve esa promesa. Gracias de antemano. En el código comento sobre la línea donde deseo mostrar por consola los datos que me devuelve la promesa, pero me devuelve: Promise {} en lugar del token.

//Express

```
    'use strict';
//import User from "../models/user";
const models = require('./../models');
const User = models.User;

var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

function generateToken(user) {
    var u = {
        username: user.nickname
    };
    return jwt.sign(u, 'hgjhbjh ghj gyhj', {
        expiresIn: 60 * 60 * 24 // expires in 24 hours
    });
}

module.exports = {
    userLog: function userLog(req, res) {
        return User.findOne({
            where: {
                nickname: req.params.nickname,
                password: req.params.password
            }
        })
            .then(function(user) {
                let token = generateToken(user);
                return res.status(200).send(token);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                res.status(400).send(error);
            });
    }
};


//React

    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form, Icon, Input, Button, Checkbox } from 'antd';
import { GlobalStyle } from './Styles';
import { userLog } from '../FetchServer';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

class Login extends Component {
    state = {
        token: ''
    };

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
            if (!err) {
                console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
                var token = userLog(values);
                console.log(token);//Esta linea de codigo me devuelve (Promise {<pending>}) y deveria devolverme el token
            }
        });
    };

    render() {
        if (this.state.token !== '') return <Redirect to="/home" />;
        const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
        return (
            <GlobalStyle id="components-form-demo-normal-login">
                <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="login-form">
                    <Form.Item>
                        {getFieldDecorator('userName', {
                            rules: [ { required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' } ]
                        })(
                            <Input
                                prefix={<Icon type="user" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />}
                                placeholder="Username"
                            />
                        )}
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item>
                        {getFieldDecorator('password', {
                            rules: [ { required: true, message: 'Please input your Password!' } ]
                        })(
                            <Input
                                prefix={<Icon type="lock" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />}
                                type="password"
                                placeholder="Password"
                            />
                        )}
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item>
                        {getFieldDecorator('remember', {
                            valuePropName: 'checked',
                            initialValue: true
                        })(<Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>)}
                        <a className="login-form-forgot" href="register">
                            Forgot password
                        </a>
                        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" className="login-form-button">
                            Log in
                        </Button>
                        Or <a href="register">register now!</a>
                    </Form.Item>
                </Form>
            </GlobalStyle>
        );
    }
}

const WrappedNormalLoginForm = Form.create({ name: 'normal_login' })(Login);

ReactDOM.render(<WrappedNormalLoginForm />, document.getElementById('root'));

export default WrappedNormalLoginForm;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay que  manejar la promesa y resolverla ya que al parecer estás manejando código asíncrono al querer obtener el token.

Puedes usar Promises y su [api](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise) para resolverlas o [async await.](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona)

Aquí un ejemplo:

```
userLog(values).then(token => console.log(token)).catch(e => console.log(e))
```

Dentro del .then obtendrás el resultado de la promesa resuelta y el .catch entra sólo cuando hay una excepción.

Con async await sería:

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.form.validateFields(async (err, values) => {
            if (!err) {
                console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
                var token = await userLog(values);
                console.log(token);
            }
        });
    };
```

Esto es una manera más legible de resolver promesas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta J.Correa, era lo que necesitaba para resolver mi problema.